# Hide video if src is empty angular

Tags: angularjs

So I have video which src i load from json.
And it's working great but it also shows video element inside div even if src is empty.
How to remove video if src of video is empty?

```
<video ng-show="rand.embeder !== ''"  autoplay loop>
   <source  src="{{rand.embeder}}" type="video/mp4">    
</video>
```

Comment: try `ng-show="rand.embeder"`

Comment: you are testing if rand.embeder is strictly an empty string.  perhaps it is instead undefined ?  For this test a truthy comparison ie != should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<video ng-show="rand.embeder"  autoplay loop>
    <source  src="{{rand.embeder}}" type="video/mp4">    
</video>
```